# get bytes from socket data event nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, tcp, tls1.2

I have a kinda weird problem

I've been trying to implement my own tls implementation to be able to connect to a server that is not 100% compliant to the TLSv1.2 specification (the client_random and server_random are not random but generated from a timestamp, and the server forces the client to have the record layer version be tls 1.2 to perform the handshake)

On top of that I needed to send some data in clearText in a protocol similar to http but not http (sts/1.0) before I can start the tls handshake

so I hacked together a implementation to both things, but I'm hitting something that I did not know could happen

when receiving the server's certificate in the tls handshake, the bytes that I see in the buffer I created with `Buffer.from(data, "ascii")` (yes the socket encoding is also ascii) (and I also tried with utf-8 encoding) were `not` the ones I was seeing in wireshark and are leading to my x509 parser to fail (if works if I create a buffer from the copy pasted hex stream of the certificate from wireshark). I believe this is a encoding issue, but then what encoding can I use to get the raw bytes in `data` without having to encode it ?

example:

beginning of certificate message in wireskark:

```
16:03:03:03:52:0b:00:03:4e:00:03:4b
```

beginning of certificate message in nodejs encoded in ascii:

```
16:03:03:00:2a:02:00:00:26:03:03:12
```

The socket is use is the one from `net.Socket`

My plan at the time of writing this to solve this issue is to have a low level language act as a proxy, receive the raw bytes, create the ascii representation of those bytes, then send that to my nodejs socket. not the best solution at all but that's all I could find on my own.

PS: if anyone knows a nodejs tls implementation that can accept a specific client_random and/or force the tls record layer version to be 1.2 during the handshake, you would save me tens of hours of developping everything I need.

PS2: I tried to look for a "raw" tcp socket on nodejs to get more control on the data I receive, and there is a "raw-socket" npm package. But from what I saw there is no way to set the port you want to connect to on the server. If anyone used this package before and knows how to set a port in a tcp socket under that package, I'd like to understand how you did it.

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I used a python proxy to send me the ascii representation of those bytes and everything works. I'm quite frustrated I couldn't find a way to do it in node without having to do a damn .node